# Problems setting up worker MPM

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mpm-worker, i386

Can't get MPM Worker to work..

I've installed the `php-zts` package, uncommented `#HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker` in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` and restarted the httpd service.

the httpd printout:

```
[root@web06 ~]# httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   Sep  3 2009 17:38:51
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:3
Server loaded:  APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Compiled using: APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

the Apache:

```
[root@web06 ~]# apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   Sep  3 2009 17:41:45
[root@web06 ~]# apachectl -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  worker.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
```

Server's details:

```
Linux web 2.6.18-164.15.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Wed Mar 17 12:14:29 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

How come the https still works in prefork mode?

I feel I miss something really basic..

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

```
[root@web06 ~]# ps -ef | grep httpd
apache    4366 14700  0 05:44 ?        00:00:34 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9239 14700  0 06:07 ?        00:00:22 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9260 14700  0 06:07 ?        00:00:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9271 14700  0 06:07 ?        00:00:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9288 14700  0 06:07 ?        00:00:22 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9337 14700  0 06:07 ?        00:00:23 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     14700     1  0 Aug08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14702 14700  0 Aug08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   22445 14700  0 06:57 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   22480 14700  0 06:57 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   27910 14700  0 07:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   27917 14700  0 07:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     27948  9898  0 07:11 pts/2    00:00:00 grep httpd
```

**EDIT 2**

```
[root@web06 ~]# ls -l /usr/sbin/httpd*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 315284 Sep  3  2009 /usr/sbin/httpd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 327708 Sep  3  2009 /usr/sbin/httpd.event
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 327708 Sep  3  2009 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker

[root@web06 ~]# cat /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Thu Aug 09 07:26:14 2012] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context root:system_r:httpd_t
[Thu Aug 09 07:26:14 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Aug 09 07:26:14 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Aug 09 07:26:14 2012] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 6 max processes and 25 max threads.
[Thu Aug 09 07:26:14 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

**EDIT 3**

```
[root@web06 conf]# grep '/etc/sysconfig/httpd' /etc/init.d/httpd
# config: /etc/sysconfig/httpd
if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/httpd ]; then
        . /etc/sysconfig/httpd
# Set HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker in /etc/sysconfig/httpd to use a server
```

**EDIT 4**

Output of [`sh -x /etc/init.d/httpd start > /tmp/apache.debug 2>&1`](http://pastebin.com/z1XEWz8q)

**EDIT 5**

After running the commands by @quanta:

```
[root@web06 ~]# ps -ef | grep httpd
root     16303     1  0 08:29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
apache   16305 16303  2 08:29 ?        00:00:37 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
apache   16307 16303  2 08:29 ?        00:00:35 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
root     20415 20381  0 08:56 pts/1    00:00:00 grep httpd
```

Comment: we all know here that you must be running redhat or centos as you are talking about /etc/sysconfig/httpd. But please specify os version and tag it so that people who are looking for the answer might find it.

Comment: `ps -ef | grep httpd`?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/sbin/httpd*`? `tail -30 /var/log/httpd/error_log` after restarting?

Comment: Lack of the asterisk at the end. Make sure that `/usr/sbin/httpd.worker` exists and executable. Also post the init script `/etc/init.d/httpd`?

Comment: `grep '/etc/sysconfig/httpd' /etc/init.d/httpd`?

Comment: @quanta question updated.

Comment: Stop Apache and `sh -x /etc/init.d/httpd start > /tmp/apache.debug 2>&1` and upload this file to pastebin.

Comment: `ps -ef | grep httpd` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why the first check `ps -ef | grep httpd` still shows `/usr/sbin/httpd` but since I see the belows in the debug:

```
+ /bin/bash -c 'ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; /usr/sbin/httpd.worker'
...
+ success 'httpd.worker startup'
```

I'm pretty sure that your Apache is running in worker mode, and the second check prove that:

```
[root@web06 ~]# ps -ef | grep [h]ttpd
root     16303     1  0 08:29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
apache   16305 16303  2 08:29 ?        00:00:37 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
apache   16307 16303  2 08:29 ?        00:00:35 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
```

**DON'T** use `httpd -V` to check the mode which Apache is running in, because:

```
# which httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd
```

Use `apachectl -V` (uppercase) instead:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   Oct 20 2011 17:03:44
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:3
Server loaded:  APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Compiled using: APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Worker
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/worker"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

or `/server-info`:

```
$ lynx -dump http://yourdomain.com/server-info | grep -i mpm
   MPM Name: Worker
   MPM Information: Max Daemons: 1 Threaded: yes Forked: yes
   Server Built With: -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork" -D
          AcceptMutex - Valid accept mutexes for this platform and MPM
```

Comment: I don't get it.. You are right.. it is working.. but i didn't change any settings!!!! weird... anyways, thats so much for your time, effort, and explanation!